# Where is the mistake in this code?

Tags: php

I'm a noobie in php, so I got this code from my teacher and I can't get the answer. Can somebody explain me where is the mistake is this code?

```
<?php
function XXX($array, $val) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if ($value == $val) {
 unset($value);
  return $key;
  break;
 }
}
 return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Please use a more meaningful title and show us any errors which have been displayed. If no errors are being displayed, check if error reporting is enabled? If not please enable it. Try and include all the code and not just the extracts as you may have errors in other parts.

Comment: Ah yes, been a while since I seen the homework questions! Have you run this? Got an error?

Comment: What is the question your teacher has asked you? What is the purpose of the code?

Comment: You never call the function?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions **without** a **clear problem statement** are **not** useful to other readers.*

Comment: Your code is not wrong. Its working as intended. To show you its working: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c0cf41e56f715c7ee475e362509db8b8acea378

Comment: Maybe... you never hit the `break`, so it's not needed?

Answer (score 3):

The function is working correctly, but it does not `unset` anything because you are using it wrong, you have the function unsetting `$value` where it should actually unset `$array[$key]`.

Comment: Good spot. Though it most likely seems that this the issue, we'll have to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: + it has an unreachable break statement.

Comment: @M.I. another good spot, seems like a lot is wrong with this code.